# Form mailto is not working when viewing in mobile.What to do?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

[After filling up the form,its properly working in desktop. Its opening my browser and sending mail to the target address... But,, in mobile view,its not working, after clicking on SEND button,nothing happening.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1UPJ.png)

[picture of the layout/website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRMVA.png)

Comment: No images, post your code here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.